# not having to encode url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, encoding

Say I have this url "/my#stuff"

I am using asp.net mvc and when I try to goto this page it takes me to just "/my". The "#stuff" part has been removed.

Now I can get it to work fine if I encode the URL like so "/my%23stuff" since %23 decodes to #

However, is there a way I can get this to work without having to encode the url?

I'd like it if typing in "/my#stuff" as the URL worked just the same as "my%23stuff"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do what you are saying. The hash is used in a URL for anchor tags.

You are pointing at a page /my and navigating to anchor tag "stuff" on that page. If anchor tag "stuff" does not exist it will just navigate to page /my.

Comment: Actually, that's the rule for HTTP URLs - but I can imagine you're skipping that level of detail considering the example in the question is missing at least the protocol and hostname.